# Monitor linux server and/or log files using the terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Sometime ago when I was first configuring a linux server with Rails I found a nice linux monitor from the terminal. It had percentages and text-based bars showing up. It had a nice text-graphics interface. But I thought: "I will come back to it once I finish the app". So now I finished the app and can't remember in what server I installed it and what tool it was.

Is there a nice linux server monitor open source software that displays live data through the terminal? With colors and bars?

Comment: Please post these kinds of questions on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).  See [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to this list: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.html
Also: http://htop.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yes! it was htop! Thank you. For reference, I also searched my history and this is one of the pages I used for installing and basic instructions http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/using-htop-to-monitor-system-processes-on-linux/